# SQL - can you select everything where a certain string ends with a few characters?

Tags: mysql, sql

Can you do a "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE attribute has last character which is 'A' or 'B'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see, that everyone who answered here suggest `LIKE`.
However, the following would be faster than `LIKE`, so I suggest you use it.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM t1
 WHERE substring(attribute, -1)= 'A'
       OR substring(attribute, -1)= 'B';
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e70c/1)

Comment: This did not work in redbrick, but it did in oracle.  I don't have mysql.  But I do like the answer, so I voted for it.

Comment: Awesome, @Alexander, I'm so glad that someone finally built something like sqlfiddle!

Comment: @Kzqai I'm excited too :) They're accepting donations btw :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE attribute LIKE '%A' OR attribute LIKE '%B'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE attribute LIKE '%A' or attribute LIKE '%B'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE attribute LIKE '%A' OR attribute LIKE '%B';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [**Mysql's RIGHT()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_right) function

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  `table` 
WHERE RIGHT(attribute, 1) = 'A' 
  OR RIGHT(attribute, 1) = 'B'
```

[Small Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/32562)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. For instance you could:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE attribute LIKE '%[AB]'
```

Which would select all rows in table with field 'attribute' ending in either 'A' or 'B'